# MVC user format output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, format, actionresult, jsonresult

I have a C# MVC Project, and allow for users to select the way in which their data can be outputted (i.e. speed in kmh/mph, time in CST, ESt, etc., Distance in KMs, Miles, Meters, Hecters, etc.).  Rather than running back to the db each time to retrieve the settings, on logon i stuff it into the encrypted cookies user data portion.  I am also using the service-repository pattern where my services are implemented in the BLL and models defined in the BOL. I am also returning the data as JsonResults (using NewtonSoft Library). What is the best strategy (where and how) to convert the data to the user specified type without passing this unit preference information into the Business Logic Layers? I was initially thinking about using customAttributes and writing my own CustomJsonResult actionResult, that would use reflection and generate the Json string, but this would require my own object traversal algorithm.  My primary concern is that i want to make my app stateless.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this conversion could be performed in the mapping layer which converts your business objects into view models that are passed to the view. So the controller would query the business layer to retrieve a model then will query the user preference which was stored into a cookie and would pass those two entities to the mapping layer which will perform the necessary conversions and formatting based on the user locale and return a view model ready to be transmitted to the strongly typed view which would simply output the information.

Another possibility is to use custom HTML helpers inside your view which would take the model value and based on the user preferences stored into the cookie output perform the conversion and output the formatted string.

Comment: Hey Darin, thanks for the insight, however I am passing my Data back to differing ActionResults i.e JsonResult(), CSVResult(), etc. Thus, i need that data in the correct format before i send it to these default methods. You are correct I could do this with static helper functions IF i was rendering to html views. But I am not :s

Comment: @Amit, then my first suggestion for performing the conversion in the mapping layer stays valid.